# Passing custom jtable modeltable classes as parameters

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have a jframe with a tappedpane that has 
 two tabs. Each tab contains a jtable
 and each jtable is connected to a separate tablemodel
The jframe class has a renderer method 
that  adjusts the width of the column to 
the length of the longest text in the column
The renderer method is hard coded to one of the 
table models. But will like to pass the tablemodel classes 
to the renderer method as variables.

this is the code for the modeldata

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<List<Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
     private String[] header = { "ID","SUBJECT","LETTTER FROM","LETTER DATE","DATE RECEIED",
                                  "REMARKS","DATE DISPATCHED","DESTINATION OFFICE"};
     private int minRowCount = 5;

    public MyTableModel()
    {  }

    public List<List<Object>> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<List<Object>> dataList) {       
        this.dataList = dataList;
        fireTableDataChanged();       
        fireTableStructureChanged();        
    }

    public void setHeader(String[] header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String[] getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return Math.max(minRowCount, dataList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return header.length;
    }

    @Override
   public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return header[col];
   }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
        Object value = null;
        if(row < dataList.size())      
        {value = dataList.get(row).get(col);}
        return value;
    }


    @Override
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {   
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }              
            }
            return Object.class;
        }
    }
```

this is the code initialising the tabemdel bject in the jframe class

```
MyTableModel myModel = new MytableModel();
```

below is the code of the renderer method

```
 public final void setColumnWidth( )
    { int width = 0;  //width of column
      int headerWidth = 0; //width of header

     //create header renderrer 
      final TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = resultTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer(); 

        for(int myColumn = 0 ;myColumn < resultTable.getColumnCount(); myColumn++)
    {  width = 0;
       headerWidth = 0;
       width = 0;
   Component hcomp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
           resultTable, resultTable.getModel().getColumnName(myColumn), false, false, 0, myColumn);
   headerWidth = Math.max(hcomp.getPreferredSize().width , headerWidth);
   resultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(myColumn).setPreferredWidth(headerWidth);

   //iterate through the rows to find the widest cell
      for (int row = 0; row < resultTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
     TableCellRenderer renderer = resultTable.getCellRenderer(row, myColumn);
     Component comp = resultTable.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, myColumn);
     width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
      width = Math.max(width, headerWidth);

      //set the columnwith to the widest cell
      resultTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(myColumn).setPreferredWidth(width);
 }   
    }     }
```

the problem is that the table model 
classes each extend the AbstractModelTable

any suggestion on how to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> below is the code of the renderer method

That is not a renderer method. It is just a method.

> the problem is that the table model classes each extend the AbstractModelTable

That doesn't matter. A renderer belongs to the table not the model. So the code you posted for the setColumnWidth() method will work for any JTable. What you really need to do is change the code to accept a parameter for the table that you want to work with. So the method should look like:

```
public void setColumnWidth(JTable table)
{
    ...
}
```

Now everywhere in that method where you see the variable "resultTable", you should change it to "table".

Another option is to use the [TableColumnAdjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) which is already a separate class that you can use with any table.